# Python pega o primeiro valor da coluna ao invés do ultimo

Tags: mysql, python, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando pegar o último registro de uma coluna no MySQL porém o Python só retorna "1", é um registro de ID com auto_incriment. Tentei de várias formas, em algumas me era retornado a coluna inteira,em outras era retorna "1". Atualmente o código está assim:

```
d = cur.execute("SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Pings")
```

Comment: Se você rodar este comando direto no banco qual é o resultado apresentado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As chamadas a SQL do Python, em qualquer driver, são feitas em duas partes: em uma você chama o método "execute" do cursor, como você faz - essa chamada só retorna o número de resultados encontrados, não os resultados em si - por isso sua variável `d`contém sempre 1.

Para de fato recuperar os resultados da query QL, você chama um novo método em Python - por exemplo - o  fetchall` que retorna todos os seus resultados.

No seu caso, pode ficar assim:

```
cur.execute("SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Pings")
d = cur.fetchall()[0]
```

(se for um resultado só, pode-se usar o `retchone` também.

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado!

Comment: (se funcionou, você pode marcar a resposta como aceita)

Answer (score 0):

d = cur.execute("SELECT Id FROM Pings ORDER BY Id DESC")